# Running Tcl on apache tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, tcl

I was wandering if there is any solution such as Apach Rivet wich fit Apache Tomcat 6.
My problem is that i want to load all neccessery pacages for running my up once and use it for all request recieved.

I wish to do it on Apache Tomcat since other parts of my app is running on it and i dont want to support two servers such as tclhttpd.

I though of using apach CGI Servlet but that just run my script and release the resource on end and i get the same effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[JTcl](http://jtcl.kenai.com/) is an implementation of Tcl written in Java; that should be usable from within a Tomcat webapp. However, I've never actually tried it, so I don't know if there are any problems with resource releasing on the unload of the webapp.
You might also have a problem with your script as JTcl implements quite an old version of Tcl if I remember right. The best way to find out if you're OK with JTcl is probably to try it (first with a simple script that just does something like reporting the version, then with your real scripts).

If you can't make it work for your scripts, running a standard Tcl interpreter (or a Starpack) through something like CGI is your best bet. (Tcl is typically a lot lighter weight than Java, so the overhead of CGI doesn't bite nearly so hard. There are other options to accelerate too.)

Comment: Heh. Better to use JTcl than Jacl; it's both more recent and more complete. All the rest of the advice still applies though.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use native libraries, then [TclBlend](http://tcljava.sourceforge.net/docs/website/index.html) could be worth a look. There are some problems when you use it with Tcl > 8.4 from Tcl (aka load Java into Tcl, but this is not what you want)

Both Jacl and TclBlend uses the same API on both Tcl and Java side, JTcl is (afaik) a fork of Jacl.